# pybind11: Convert boost::container::vector to list

Tags: c++, vector, boost, type-conversion, pybind11

Similar to the `type_caster` for a `boost::optional` described in the [pybind11 documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html)  I need one for a `boost::container::vector<T>`.

I was trying

```
namespace pybind11 { namespace detail {
template<typename T>
struct type_caster<boost::container::vector<T>> : list_caster<boost::container::vector<T>, boost::container::allocator<T>>
{
};
}}   // namespace pybind11::detail
```

which unfortunately did not work.

As the vector is fairly big, I also need to avoid copying it and hence also declared:

```
PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(boost::container::vector<SomeCustomStruct>)
```

Comment: Can you show more self contained code that reproduces it, or at least be more specific about "which unfortunately did not work."

Comment: Maybe try `py::bind_vector`?